# Create custom extensions or plugins in Typo3 6.0.4

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I am a new TYPO3 user.

How to create an extension or plugin in Typo3 V 6.0, which will take an UID as an input and return the titles of the root page and its child pages if any. I am also using FLUID templates to display the returned data on the front end.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: This is also possible with pure ``TypoScript``. You can just use an ``HMENU`` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Extension Builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) in version 2.5.0+ is dedicated for creating extensions in TYPO3 ver 6.0+

`FE plugin` is just some action in your `extension`, play a little with builder, so you'll get familiar with the concept soon.

Comment: I started using Extension Builder. However, I'm stuck at this [FE Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455164/frontend-plugin-options-not-displaying-for-extension-builder)