# Frontend Plugin options not displaying for Extension Builder

Tags: plugins, typo3

I created an extension with a frontend plugin using Extension Builder called "Planner".

The plugin is listed while editing the page content (Inserting into the page), however, the ***plugin options are not being displayed.***

The actions created in the controller are List, Index, Show, Edit, New. 
The folder structure in conf/ext also seems fine. 
The table table tx_planner_domain_model_planner has also been created.

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `FlexForms` (TYPO3 wiki: http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms).

This makes it possible to provide a form where you can manage your plugin settings.

See also: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/current/

Comment: Is this a solution to the problem? Idk, I'm new to typo3. Ideally, shouldn't my edit page show the plugin options ? 
I'm assuming there is something I need to change in the settings of the extension?

Comment: "Edit page" shows only options from the `pages` table of your database and is configured by the TCA. If you need there for some kind of reason options for your plugin you should extend this table.

Comment: Options for your plugin should be manage in the `content-element` that inserts the plugin on the page. You can reach that with FlexForms.

Comment: Ok. Quick question, now why is that when I insert plugins like "News System", it gives me Plugin Options right away ? Also in this (http://typo3.org/videos/play/t3con11fr-coding-lazydevelopmentusingtheextensionbuilder-hd/) video, they don't seem to use any other resources... why is that ?

Comment: I think you are confused by the difference between a `table` (or simply your `model`) and a plugin that is connected with your controller that serves for example a list of your objects (records)?

Comment: Via `List` view you can insert a new `record`, there you can find your planner object.

Comment: I appreciate you answering patiently, but i'm not sure what you trying to say. Let me just explain my issue. I created an extension with a frontend plugin named `Planner`. This extension has a database table(model) called `tx_planner_domain_model_planner`with fields `datePlan` and `titlePlan` to be added from the frontend. Now, I insert this plugin to a page. The problem is that I do not know where to enter these records and how to show them. The controller has list, new and show actions. I hope I made myself clear. Thank You :)